# Remove all li from ul inside a div

Tags: jquery

I need to remove all items from a list that is inside a div using jQuery

The problem is that the ul has no class or id but the div has an id.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want

```
$('#myDiv ul li').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('#myDiv > ul').empty();
```

Comment: so what is the purpose of the greater character? is it like a selector or more like a direction what to check for?

Comment: @user2818430 `>` means direct child of `div with id myDiv` not grandchildren.Read [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)